# Проблема в написании скрипта Python для проверки валидности ссылки

Tags: python, requests, urllib

Пытаюсь написать простенький скрипт, который должен проверять валидность ссылки. Использую два способа.

Певрый способ:

```
import urllib3

url = 'https://ierusalimskaya.otelms.com'

def check(url):
    try:
        urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False

print(check(url))
```

Возвращается `False`, хотя ссылка вполне рабочая.

Второй способ:

```
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = 'https://ierusalimskaya.otelms.com'
resp = http.request('GET', url, )
print(resp.status)
```

В данном случае получаю целую гирлянду ошибок. При этом на других ссылках оба метода работают вполне корректно.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону вообще можно копать?

Comment: Ну вы бы хотя бы написали `Exception as e: print(e.err)` или как там, и в вопрос варианты ошибок.

Comment: вообще странно, у меня оба метода нормально отрабатывают на этой ссылке. Было бы интересно посмотреть на ошибки, которые выдаются